# Probability distribution of product of a dependent indicator function with a Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $c_1,c_2, k_1,k_2$ are constants and $X_1,X_2 \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$. What would be the distribution of the random variable:

$$Z = \mathbb 1_{\{k_1X_1 + k_2X_2 \geq 0\}} \cdot (c_1X_1+c_2X_2)$$

Normally I would use the towering property of expectations/probability, but I am unable to do it here due to the complicated nature of relationship between the two events.

Comment: Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MushuNrek yes they are indepedendent.

Comment: I am not sure that you can get something explicit here... The way I would think about this is to write for $x \geq 0$
$$
\mathbb P(Z \leq x) = \mathbb P( k_1 X_1 + k_2X_2 < 0 ) + \mathbb P( k_1 X_1 + k_2 X_2 \geq 0, c_1X_1 + c_2X_2 \leq x).
$$
The first part should be easy to compute as a linear combination of independent normals is again normal. For the second, solve for $X_1$ and condition on $X_2$.

Comment: @MushuNrek thanks. I had figured out the same...I was too lazy to write it. Although I would suggest computing the second part using a graphical method. Integrate over some kind of polyhedra.

Comment: I feel you xD Here is a quick computation: the first probability is equal to 1/2. For the second part, if we suppose that all constants are positive, we get
$$
\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\int_\mathbb{R} \int_{-k_2x_2/k_1}^{ (x - c_2x_2)/c_1} \exp\left( -\dfrac{x_1^2 + x_2^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) dx_1 dx_2
$$
or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote
$$U = k_1 X_1 + k_2 X_2$$
$$V = c_1 X_1 + c_2 X_2$$
then $U,V$ follow the normal distributions  (for plus information, the vector $(U,V)^T$ follows a bivariate normal distribution)
$$U \sim \mathcal{N}(0,(k_1^2+k_2^2)\sigma^2)$$
$$V \sim \mathcal{N}(0,(c_1^2+c_2^2)\sigma^2)$$
It's easy to compute the correlation between $U$ and $V$
$$\rho =\frac{k_1c_1 +k_2c_2}{\sqrt{(k_1^2+k_2^2)(c_1^2+c_2^2)}}$$

There existes a normal random variable $T \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, independent to $U$ and $V$ such that
$$\frac{\text{sign}(\rho)}{\sqrt{c_1^2+c_2^2}}V=\sqrt{|\rho|} T+\frac{\sqrt{1-|\rho|}}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}U$$

Then
$$Z = \mathbf{1}_{\{U \ge 0  \}} V =\text{sign}(\rho)\cdot\sqrt{c_1^2 + c_2^2}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{U \ge 0  \}}  \left(\sqrt{|\rho|} T+\frac{\sqrt{1-|\rho|}}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}U  \right)$$

Let $\varphi$ and $\Phi$ denote the density function and cdf of the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, we compute the cdf of $Z$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Z\le z) &= \mathbb{E}( \mathbf{1}_{\{Z \le z  \}})\\
&= \mathbb{E} (\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{Z \le z  \}}|U ))  \\
&= \mathbb{E} (\mathbb{P}(Z \le z|U ))  \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left(\mathbb{P}(\{Z \le z\}\cap \{U \le 0\}|U )+\mathbb{P}(\{Z \le z\}\cap \{U \ge 0\}|U)\right)  \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{z \ge 0  \}}+\mathbb{P}\left( \{\text{sign}(\rho)\cdot\sqrt{c_1^2 + c_2^2}  \left(\sqrt{|\rho|} T+\frac{\sqrt{1-|\rho|}}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}U  \right)\le z\} \cap \{U \ge 0\} |U \right)\right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{z \ge 0  \}}+\mathbb{E} \left(\mathbf{1}_{\{U \ge 0  \}}\cdot\mathbb{P}\left( \text{sign}(\rho)\cdot\sqrt{c_1^2 + c_2^2}  \left(\sqrt{|\rho|} T+\frac{\sqrt{1-|\rho|}}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}U  \right)\le z  |U \right)\right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{z \ge 0  \}}+\mathbb{E} \left(\mathbf{1}_{\{U \ge 0  \}}\cdot\Phi\left(  \frac{z}{\sqrt{|\rho|}\cdot\sqrt{c_1^2 + c_2^2}} - \text{sign}(\rho)\frac{\sqrt{1-|\rho|}}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}U \right)\right)  \\
\mathbb{P}(Z\le z)&= \color{red}{ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{z \ge 0  \}}+\int_{0}^{+\infty} \left(\Phi\left(  \frac{z}{\sqrt{|\rho|}\cdot\sqrt{c_1^2 + c_2^2}} - \text{sign}(\rho)\frac{\sqrt{1-|\rho|}}{\sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}}u \right)\right)\varphi(u)du } \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You cannot be very explicit. For simplicity consider $Y$ and $Z$ independent and $N(0,1)$ consider $X=Y-kZ$ with $k>0$ and let us look for the distribution of $Y_1=Y1_{X>0}.$ The conditional density of $Y_1$ knowing $Z$ is $$f_Z(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}1_{y>kZ}\frac{1}{1-\Phi(kZ)}$$ where $\Phi(y)=\Pr(Y<y).$ The asked density of $Y_1$ is therefore the impossible integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{z}(y)dy=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}\int_{-\infty}^{y/k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\frac{1}{1-\Phi(kz)}dz.$$